# Slideshow from jpg files

Tags: ffmpeg, slideshow

Have an command to make slideshow mp4 from *.jpg files:

`ffmpeg -r 1/3 -f concat -safe 0 -i <(ls -v *.jpg | sed "s|^|file '$PWD/|") -vf "scale='min(1920,iw)':min'(1080,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -preset slow -crf 14 slideshow.mp4`

Need good effects from one jpg to another like morphing or just fade in fade out, not just "one picture 3 sec, next picture 3 sec, etc."
OpenAI or ChatGPT little bit dummy for this problem, so need human knowledge and intellect :)

Comment: A simple alternative is to use `shotwell`, which is installed by default in Ubuntu Desktop. You can choose between several transition styles, and need not create a video clip (which saves a lot of drive space.

Comment: But I prefer an even simpler alternative, but without any fancy transitions, `feh`. I have two aliases, `alias feha='feh -r -F -V -d -Z'` and
`alias fehs='feh -r -F -V -d -Z -z -D 5'` where `fehs` is a slideshow with random order of pictures. Modify according to `man feh`

Comment: Thank you @sudodus but I need exactly mp4 file to make possibility view slideshow not only from Ubuntu but from mediaplayer, tv, smartphone etc.

Comment: I have used Openshot to merge video clips and also show pictures. There are many nice transitions between clips and pictures available. I have only used it via a GUI. I don't know if / how you can run it in batch mode. - I have used `ffmpeg` several years ago, but never fiddled with fancy transitions. - Let us hope that an experienced ffmpeg user will see your question and help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research around this problem. Looks like it’s not easy to construct a one line command. Need a script with several steps describing the effects between each individual picture. Something with `-loop 1 -i './01.jpg' -loop 1 -i './02.jpg'` use `filter_complex` and something like `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split=2[stream1out1][stream1out2];[stream2blurred][stream2raw]` step by step.
This is useful [github link](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-video-slideshow-scripts) with slideshow-scripts, e.g. blurred background, fade in/out, zoom in/out.  But this scripts eat many memory, slow generation time, and big mp4 final size.
So looks like initial command not so bad for using as is.